# Why when merging this two dataframes one of the columns is full of NANs?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframes. They have the same rows and different columns. The have one column matching: "ID".

Dataframe 1 has 17 columns. Dataframe 2 has 2 columns.

I want to create a Dataframe 3 with the 17 columns of DF1 and one column from DF2.

For example:

DF1.

```
ID    COL1

051    D
041    A
039    Z
031    H
021    H
074    M
021    M
044    I
025    N
030    N
008    N
073    N
030    N
020    K
```

DF2.

```
ID     MONTH

051      07
041      07
039      09 
031      10
021      09
074      01
021      02
044      01
025      10
030      03
008      03
073      03
030      03
020      03
```

now I do the merge using this code

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on= ["ID",df1.index], right_on = ["ID", df2.index], how = "left").drop('key_1',1 )
```

And the result is

DF3.

```
 ID     MONTH     COL1
051      07        nan
041      07        nan
039      09        nan
031      10        nan
021      09        nan
074      01        nan
021      02        nan
044      01        nan
025      10        nan
030      03        nan
008      03        nan
073      03        nan
030      03        nan
020      03        nan
```

Whats going on?

Comment: remove the df.index...

Comment: Can you check if the joined columns have the same `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, ID both are int

Comment: Working removing df.index!! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

try this [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) use on if both column name on which you are joining is same

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["ID"],how = "left")
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID"],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Could be but the Dataframes i used as example are not the real dataframe. In the real dataframe there are 15 millon rows. And there are plenty of duplicates. So when I do the merge the rows of DF3 instead of having 15 millon rows go to 16.7 millon rows and I dont want that.

Comment: duplicates on the basis of ID ?

Comment: @Lazzal ihave drop_duplicates on the ID